# Any idea how to make a button using TUI in C?

Tags: c, windows, console, tui

I'm working on a console-based C project and I want it to have some buttons.

- How can I add some?
- How can I manage focus?

I'm using `windows.h` for making TUI.

Comment: *How* are you "using Windows.h for making TUI"? Unless you've found a copy of the (mostly long-forgotten) MEWEL library, that sounds pretty close to impossible. If you are using MEWEL, then you'd create a button by simply calling CreateWindow, passing the BUTTON class, just like you would in normal Windows programming.

Comment: The poster is probably referring to the console I/O functions: SetConsoleCursorPosition, SetConsoleTextAttribute, and so on. It's the "modern" equivalent of the DOS-era Borland conio.h functions.

Comment: @ChrisV: I'm aware of them. I wrote some code using them back around the NT 3.51/NT 4 era, but I stand by the "pretty close to impossible" statement -- call it "modern" if you will, but it was actually quite a bit *easier* to write a text-based UI on MS-DOS than using the console functions.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I should use PURE C. I can't use C++ codes. So I can't use classes. Now, can I use text-based UI? Do you know any good tutorials?

Answer (score 3):

Basically use the panels library (add on to ncurses) and make a second window, with a border, that contains your "button text".  Remember to specify the z order such that the second window floats over the first, preferably over a non-text containing portion of the first.

Then bind the key navigation, and mouse enter / exit routines of other windows direct focus to the "next" desired window and to toggle that window's color (to indicate highlighting).  Finally supply the window with a key handler to capture enter / space / whatever as a button click (which can then call whatever function you bind to it).

While there might be a better way to do this with the menu function, offhand I didn't discover (in my admittedly quick search) a way to hook the menu display of the "menu window" to an action other than displaying the menu window.